# Mysql CONCAT DECIMAL field

Tags: mysql, select, concatenation

Having a doubt regarding Mysql CONCAT function.

I am having a decimal field like,

```
EMP_SALARY DECIMAL(10,2) --> having following values 1000, 2000, 2000.50, 2000.25
```

I am using concat on a decimal field like,

1. `SELECT EMP_SALARY -- returns 1000, 2000, 2000.50, 2000.25`
2. `SELECT CONCAT(EMP_SALARY) -- returns 1000.00, 2000.00, 2000.50, 2000.25`

I am not sure and want to know the reason why the CONCAT appends the decimal places.